# Error:free(): invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, free, memcpy

When I am freeing my memory in this part of code...i am getting an error showing as :free(): invalid next size (fast)

```
int insertRecord(char *record,int recordSize,long dataPageNumber)
{
datapage *dataPage=(datapage *)malloc(sizeof(datapage));
readPage(dataPage,dataPageNumber);

slotentry slot;

//for checking and freeslotnumber storage
int freeSlotNumber=-1;
int negativeFlag=0;
int freeFlag=0;

if(recordSize+sizeof(slotentry)<=dataPage->cfs)
{
    slot.slotsize = recordSize;
    slot.slotaddress = dataPage->cfsptr;
    dataPage->cfs -= (recordSize+sizeof(slotentry));
    dataPage->cfsptr += recordSize;
    dataPage->slotcount++;

    memcpy(&dataPage->data[slot.slotaddress],record,recordSize);

    free(dataPage);
    return 1;
}
```

**After executing free(dataPage) i am getting the above error...**

```
typedef struct
{
   int pagenumber;
   int priority;
   long dirPageNo;
   long cfs;
   int cfsptr;
   int slotcount;
   char data[1];
} datapage;

typedef struct
{
   int slotaddress;
   int slotsize;
} slotentry;
```

I had kept the free(dataPage) before the memcpy it's working fine but after memcpy it's not working.. and showing the error....Can any one help me from this issue...

Comment: Note that this error message is a great example of **how not to write error-reporting code**. As-written, it's meaningful only to somebody debugging the internal implementation of `malloc`, and at best confusing to somebody like OP whose program crashed. A well-written error message should report something along the lines of "fatal error: this application has performed out-of-bounds memory writes and corrupted the internal state of the memory allocator."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably getting this due to writing outside the boundaries if the `dataPage->data` entry. This struct entry is just a single byte long, so unless `slot.slotaddress==0` and `recordSize==1`, you will be writing to whatever memory lies after the end of the `datapage` `struct`. This [memory corruption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption) is probably what is causing your `free` error.

To track down this type of error, I recommend running your program through `valgrind`:

```
valgrind progname args
```

This in this case, you will probably get messages about "invalid writes", which tell you that you are writing outside the boundaries of your arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost certainly writing past the end of the structure that you allocated, most likely when writing to the `data[]` member, which only has enough room for one element. (Any index greater than 0 will write past the allocated memory and is likely to overwrite meta data for the allocated block.)

And if you like getting help on stackoverflow, I'd strongly recommend you start accepting some of the answers given to you.

Answer (score 2):

Your bug might be outside of this code fragment. I strongly suggest to compile all your program with `gcc -Wall -g` (on Linux), to improve the code till no warnings are given, and to use `gdb` and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to debug your program.

If you are on some other system, try to enable all warnings and debug info during compilation, and to use a memory leak detector.

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking at your memcpy() line:
`memcpy(&dataPage->data[slot.slotaddress],record,recordSize);`

Here is the usage for that function:
`void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);`

The first argument is the destination: `&dataPage->data[slot.slotaddress]`
To me, that indicates you asking it to store data, beginning at the `dataPage->data` section of the structure that you've allocated, so you're basically overwriting your data and going past it into la-la land.